# Find out how many sequences of binary '1' are in list

Tags: python

What I am trying to do is to find out how many sequences of '1' are in a list read from the user input. For example, if my list looks like: 
    `mylist = [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]`
, then I want to print '3', because I have 3 sequences of 1.
So far I have tried to find the indexes of '0' and see if those indexes are consecutive(which means is a sequence of 1 between my 2 zero's,  but with no success.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` in a generator expression for `sum`:

```
from itertools import groupby
sum(1 for k, _ in groupby(mylist) if k)
```

This returns: `3`

Comment: This is *very* clever :D

Answer (score 2):

If you know your list is just going to be made up of ones and zeroes, then you can join everything together as a string, split the string on every occurrence of '0', and then count up all of the strings of 1s (which will be any part that's not empty).

```
>>> mylist = [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
>>> chunks_o_ones = [i for i in ''.join([str(i) for i in mylist]).split('0') if len(i) > 0]
>>> print(len(chunks_o_ones))
3
```

You could alternatively take the string and use a regular expression to find the '1' blocks:

```
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile('1+')
>>> print(len(p.findall(''.join([str(i) for i in mylist]))))
3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply diff to your list, which would be essentially

```
diff_list = []

for i in range(len(list)-1):
    diff_list[i] = list[i+1]-list[i]
```

this will give you a 1 if there is a change from 0 to 1, 0 if there was no change or -1 if there is a change from 1 to 0.  Then, you can use

```
nones = diff_list.count(1)
```

To count the number of times the transition from 0 to 1 took place. Although it wouldn't count the first sequence of ones, if the first element of your list is one so you can adjust it doing:

```
if list[0] == 1:
    nones += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Subtract every element of an array from the subsequent element. Whenever there will be a change from 0 -> 1, this difference will be 1. When ever we have a difference as 1, it means a new 1s pattern has started. In the end just add them up.

```
mylist = [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]    
sum([ 1 if (mylist[i+1] - mylist[i])==1 else 0 for i in range(len(mylist)-1)]+[1 if mylist[0]==1 else 0])
   3
```

Comment: Oh yes, you are right :) Beginning boundary condition somehow gets ignored. Let me change it.

Comment: As DIANA CAROLINA said in the answer above, you need to compare the first element of the list and increment the counter if this element is 1

Comment: Made the change :) Now, this boundary condition will be accommodated.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed her answer. She is right indeed.

Comment: You can refine this with `sum(1 for x, y in zip([0] + mylist, mylist) if x == 0 and y == 1)`. Note that you pad the first list for `zip` with `0` to take care of the edge case.